# Paypal buy now button - dynamic price by dropdown

Tags: html, button, data-binding, drop-down-menu

In the following snippet, I'd like it to change prices, depending on which style is selected by the user.

So for style 1, prices are: 1$, 2$ and 3$. 
For style 2, price are: 4$, 5$ and 6$. 
And for style 3, prices are: 7$, 8$ and 9$.

How can I modify that code to make it change prices, depending on which style is chosen?

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="testtest@hotmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="BM">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Which style?">Which style?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="os1">
          <option value="Style 1">Style 1</option>
          <option value="Style 2">Style 2</option>
          <option value="Style 2">Style 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="How many?">How many?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="os0">
          <option value="10 -">10 - $1.00 USD</option>
          <option value="100 -">100 - $2.00 USD</option>
          <option value="1000 -">1000 - $3.00 USD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="10 -">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="1.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="100 -">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="2.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="1000 -">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="3.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: In order to achieve that you will have to use javascript and modify the second dropdown according to the selection in the first, or use very hacky CSS to hide some options.

Comment: Have any idea how? haha. I just learned html and css, so I can make decent website. But havent gotten into js yet, as I don't have time at the moment. But I realy need to finish this.

Comment: I don't know any javascript. I just wanted to complete website for my familys business... I simply don't have time at the moment to start learning javascript, just to complete this one thing. And hoped I could avoid paying to someone just for this. Was worth atleast trying to get someone to help.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Miqro Why not use Jquery. It is a super easy javascript library to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook the [Change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event in jQuery and update the values accordingly.

The script included below updates your hidden field values and changes the text of the second dropdown.

You'll need to include the following line *and the script* either in the `<head>` section of your website or before the closing body tag `</body>`.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

---

Script:

```js
   $('select[name=os1]').change(function() {
 var style = $( this ).val();
  var price1, price2, price3;
  
  if(style == "Style 1"){
    price1 = "1.00";
    price2 = "2.00";
    price3 = "3.00";
  } else if(style == "Style 2"){
    price1 = "4.00";
    price2 = "5.00";
    price3 = "6.00";
  } else if (style == "Style 3"){
    price1 = "7.00";
    price2 = "8.00";
    price3 = "9.00";
  }
  
  $('select[name=os0] option[value=10]').text("10 - $" + price1 + " USD");
  $('select[name=os0] option[value=100]').text("100 - $" + price2 + " USD");
  $('select[name=os0] option[value=1000]').text("1000 - $" + price3 + " USD");
  $("input[name=option_amount0]").val(price1);
  $("input[name=option_amount1]").val(price2);
  $("input[name=option_amount2]").val(price3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="testtest@hotmail.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="BM">
      <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
      <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Which style?">Which style?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select name="os1">
              <option value="Style 1">Style 1</option>
              <option value="Style 2">Style 2</option>
              <option value="Style 3">Style 3</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="How many?">How many?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select name="os0">
              <option value="10">10 - $1.00 USD</option>
              <option value="100">100 - $2.00 USD</option>
              <option value="1000">1000 - $3.00 USD</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  <label id="output"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="10">
      <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="1.00">
      <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="100">
      <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="2.00">
      <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="1000">
      <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="3.00">
      <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

**Note** - I changed the option values of `os0` from `100 -` to `100` and so on.